# How can I get all products which have selected attributes in Prestashop

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.6

I am working on module development for Prestashop. Now I have situation in which I have to fetch all products which have selected attributes. There is a interface, where dropdown list of all active attributes are showing. And user does selects attributes as per need. Now, I want to find all the products on the basis of selected attributes.

Below are the table structure:

**Product Table:**

```
id_product   id_shop    ean    upc   quantity   price
    1            1       abc            50      16.99  
    2            1       def            25      25.99
```

**Product Combination Table**

```
id_attribute       id_product  
    1                  1  
    13                 1
    5                  1  
    1                  2  
    10                 2
```

Can anyone please help on how can I fetch products on the basis of selected attributes??

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this really basic My SQL ?

```
select * from product
where 
(
select count(*) from 
product_combination
where product_combination.id_attribute in (X,Y,Z)
and product.product_id = product_combination.product_id
) = 3
```

where X,Y,Z are the attributes the user selected, and 3 is the count of attributes selected.

If this is more involved, I think you need to edit your question to provide some more details as to exactly what the technical issue is. If its just that you dont know SQL then this isn't really the place to post your query.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. Suppose, If I select attribute 1 and 10, then query should fetch only product id 2. But according to your query it will also fetch the product id 1. With attribute id 1 and 10, there is only product that is 2